# How to solve $2^{\sin^2(x)}=\cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

$$2^{\sin^2(x)}=\cos(x)$$
How can I find the solution?

This is what I did :
$$\ln(2^{\sin^2(x)})=\ln(\cos(x))$$
$$\sin^2(x)\ln(2)=\ln(\cos(x))$$
$$(1-\cos^2(x))\ln(2)=\ln(\cos(x))$$
$$\cos^2(x)\ln(2)+\ln(\cos(x))-\ln(2)=0$$
I put : $t=\cos(x)$
$$t^2\ln(2)+\ln(t)-\ln(2)=0$$
If I want to take out the $t$ from the $\ln$, I will have more complicated equation with $\exp$ function.
I don't know if what I did helps to get the result. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Range of $2^{(\sin x)^2}$ is $[1,2]$ whereas range of $\cos x$ is $[-1,1]$, hence the only solutions is $\cos x = 2^{(\sin x)^2} = 1$

$\cos x = 1$ at $2n \pi $

$2^{(\sin x)^2} = 1 $

$\implies (\sin x) = 0$

$\implies x = n \pi $

The solutions have an intersection,
$x = 2n\pi $

Comment: Those intervals should be closed, but otherwise good.  And $\cos x$ has range $[-1,1]$.

Comment: made the edits, thanks

Comment: I think the last solution must be $x=2n\pi$